# Coffeescript ||= analogue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm primarily a Rails developer, and so in whipping up a little script for my company's Hubot instance, I was hoping to accomplish the following:

```
robot.brain.data.contacts ||= {}
```

Or, only make this new hash if it doesn't already exist.  The idea being that I want to have a contacts array added dynamically through the script so I don't have to modify Hubot's source, and I obviously don't want to overwrite any contacts I add to it.

Question: is there a quick little construct like the Rails ||= that I can use in Coffeescript to achieve the above goal?

Cheers.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use `?=` for conditional assignment:

```
speed ?= 75
```

The `?` is the "Existential Operator" in CoffeeScript, so it will test for existence (not truthiness):

```
if (typeof speed === "undefined" || speed === null) speed = 75;
```

The resulting JS is a bit different in your case, though, because you are testing an object property, not just a variable, so `robot.brain.data.contacts ?= {}` results in the following:

```
var _base, _ref;
if ((_ref = (_base = robot.brain.data).contacts) != null) {
  _ref;
} else {
  _base.contacts = {};
};
```

More info: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

Answer (score 12):

I personally use `or=` instead of `?=` mainly because that's what I call `||=` (or-equal) when I use it in Ruby.

```
robot.brain.data.contacts or= {}
```

The difference being that `or=` short-circuits when `robot.brain.data.contacts` is not `null`, whereas `?=` tests for `null` and only sets `robot.brain.data.contacts` to `{}` if not `null`.

[See the compiled difference.](http://coffeescript.org/#try:robot.brain.data.contacts%20or=%20%7B%7D%0Arobot.brain.data.contacts%20?=%20%7B%7D)

As mentioned in another post, neither method checks for the existence of `robot`, `robot.brain` or `robot.brain.data`, but neither does the Ruby equivalent.

**Edit:**

Also, in CoffeeScript `or=` and `||=` compile to the same JS.

Comment: `or=` and `?=` does not compile to the same JS. `?=` does a null check. See [this](http://coffeescript.org/#try:a%20%3D%20b%20%3D%200%0A%0Aa%20or%3D%201%3B%0Ab%20%3F%3D%201%3B) for the difference when using different variable names.

Comment: @KennethKalmer: Nobody said that they are equivalent. It is `or=` and `||=` that are equivalent, not `?=`.

Answer (score 7):

`?=` will assign a variable if it's `null` or `undefined`.

Use it like `speed ?= 25`

Answer (score 4):

It's called the existential operator in Coffeescript and is `?=`, http://coffeescript.org/. Quoting below:

> The Existential Operator
>
> It's a little difficult to check for the existence of a variable in
>   JavaScript. if (variable) comes close, but fails for zero, the empty
>   string, and false. CoffeeScript's existential operator ? returns true
>   unless a variable is null or undefined, which makes it analogous to
>   Ruby's nil?
>
> It can also be used for safer conditional assignment than ||=
>   provides, for cases where you may  be handling numbers or strings.

Answer (score 1):

The Coco dialect of CoffeeScript, http://github.com/satyr/coco , supports the array and object autovivification operators `@` and `@@`:

```
robot@brain@data@contacts.foo = 1
```

compiles to - granted, hairy-looking -

```
var _ref, _ref2;
((_ref = (_ref2 = robot.brain || (robot.brain = {})).data || (_ref2.data = {})).contacts || (_ref.contacts = {})).foo = 1;
```

which ensures that each step of the way, `robot.brain`, `brain.data`, `data.contacts` actually exists.

Of course you might just want the actual conditional assignment operator (which, according to the above answers, also exists in CoffeeScript):

```
robot.brain.data.contacts ?= {}
```

that compiles to

```
var _ref;
(_ref = robot.brain.data).contacts == null && (_ref.contacts = {});
```

Answer (score 0):

`a ||= b` means if `a` exists, do nothing. If `a` doesn't exist, make it equal to `b`.

Example1:

```
a = undefined;
console.log(a ||= "some_string") //prints some_string
```

Example2:

```
a = 10
console.log(a ||= "some_string") //prints 10
```